# Dynamic method creation from block parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, methods, hash

I have the following structure of data

```rb
array_of_hashes = [{"key"=>"2020-10-01",
  "foo"=>"100",
  "bar"=>38,
  "baz"=>19,
  "losem"=>19,
  "ipsum"=>0,
  ...},
...
]
state =  {["", nil, nil, nil, nil]=>
          #<MySimpleObject:0x0000557fb9fe4708
          @foo=0.0,
          @bar=0.0,
          @baz=0.0,
          @lorem=0.0,
          @ipsum=0.0,
          ...}
```

```rb
array_of_hashes.each_with_object(state) do |stats, memo|
  state = memo['key']

  state.foo = stats['foo'].to_d
  state.bar = stats['bar'].to_d
  state.baz = stats['baz'].to_d
  state.lorem = stats['lorem'].to_d
  state.ipsum = stats['ipsum'].to_d
  ...
end
```

How may I follow dry in this case?
I need smth to generate and execute methods in runtime like:

```
query.each_with_object(shared_state) do |stats, memo|
  state = memo['key']

  columns = %w[foo bar baz lorem ipsum ...]
  columns.each { |attribute|
    define_method attribute do #??????
      state.attribute = stats[attribute.to_s].to_d
    end
  }
end
```

As I got it define_method is not suitable for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, don't! This will make your code incredible hard to read. What you have in your first example is perfectly fine in my opinion. Not everything needs to be DRY.

If you really really want to do it, you can use `send`

```rb
query.each_with_object(shared_state) do |stats, memo|
  state = memo['key']

  columns = %w[foo bar baz lorem ipsum ...]
  columns.each do |attribute|
    state.send("#{attribute}=", stats[attribute].to_d) 
  end
end
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! 

I got your point and I will leave it as is :)